# Given two waves, 441 Hz and 700 Hz, how many samples long is each wave's period if the sample-rate is 48 kHz?

Tags: frequency, sampling, wave, periodic

The title says it all.

I have two waves, Master and Slave.  Master is at 441 Hz and Slave at 700 Hz.  The sample-rate is 48 kHz.

I want to know how to calculate the period of each wave in terms of samples.  How many samples long is each wave's period?

Please show me how to calculate this

Thanks

Comment: You know samples/second and you know cycles/second.  How do you combine those to get samples/cycle?

Comment: this is a remarkably elementary question.  maybe too elementary for the forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of these tones is an exact number of samples at 48 kHz, but you can calculate the periods as follows:

$\frac{48000}{441} = 108.84$ samples

$\frac{48000}{700} = 68.57$ samples